# Performance issue when parsing a large file line by line

Tags: python, performance

I have a set of several millions of small numbers stored in a file

I wrote a Python script that reads numbers from a tab delimited text file line by line, computes the reminders and appends the result to an output file. For some reason it consumes a lot of ram (20 Gb of ram on Ubuntu to parse a million of numbers). It also freezes the system because of frequent writes.

What is the correct way to tweak this script.

```
import os
import re

my_path = '/media/me/mSata/res/'
# output_file.open() before the first loop didn't help

for file_id in range (10,11): #10,201
    filename = my_path + "in" + str(file_id) + ".txt"

    fstr0 = ""+my_path +"out"+ str(file_id)+"_0.log"
    fstr1 = ""+my_path +"res"+ str(file_id)+"_1.log"

    with open(filename) as fp:
        stats = [0] * (512)

        line = fp.readline()

        while line:
            raw_line = line.strip()
            arr_of_parsed_numbers = re.split(r'\t+', raw_line.rstrip('\t'))

            for num_index in range(0, len(arr_of_parsed_numbers)):
                my_number = int(arr_of_parsed_numbers[num_index])

                v0 = (my_number % 257) -1     #value 257 is correct
                my_number = (my_number )//257   
                stats[v0] += 1
                v1 = my_number % 256
                stats[256+v1]+=1

                f0 = open(fstr0, "a")
                f1 = open(fstr1, "a")

                f0.write("{}\n".format(str(v0).rjust(3)))
                f1.write("{}\n".format(str(v1).rjust(3)))
                f0.close()
                f1.close() 

            line=fp.readLine()

    print(stats)

# tried output_file.close() here as well
print("done")
```

Updated:
I've ran this script under Windows 10 (10 **Mb** memory in Python.exe) and Ubuntu (10 **Gb** memory consumed). What can cause this discrepancy? Thousand times more is a lot.

his script consumes about 20Mb on Windows 10 (looking o

Comment: If you do `f0 = open(fstr0, "a")` a million times, your program will be slow.

Comment: instead of opening and closing the output files (fstr0,fstr1) for each number in each line in the entire input file, try opening them once before you start, and closing them at the end of the entire parsing

Comment: The rest of the computations can probably be optimized but will be fast enough as-is most likely

Comment: How does the `while line:` loop ever stop?

Comment: @John. Good catch. It's magic.

Comment: You run out of memory because you have an infinite loop most likely.

Comment: Sorry, incorrect copy-paste.

Comment: `fp.readLine()` <-- `readLine` is not a method...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. Note the files are only opened and closed once each, and the loop iterates once per line.

```
import os
import re

my_path = '/media/me/mSata/res/'
# output_file.open() before the first loop didn't help

for file_id in range (10,11): #10,201
    filename = my_path + "in" + str(file_id) + ".txt"

    fstr0 = ""+my_path +"out"+ str(file_id)+"_0.log"
    fstr1 = ""+my_path +"res"+ str(file_id)+"_1.log"

    with open(filename, "r") as fp, open(fstr0, "a") as f0, open(fstr1, "a") as f1:
        stats = [0] * (512)

        for line in fp:
            raw_line = line.strip()
            arr_of_parsed_numbers = re.split(r'\t+', raw_line.rstrip('\t'))

            for num_index in range(0, len(arr_of_parsed_numbers)):
                my_number = int(arr_of_parsed_numbers[num_index])

                v0 = (my_number % 257) -1     #value 257 is correct
                my_number = (my_number )//257   
                stats[v0] += 1
                v1 = my_number % 256
                stats[256+v1]+=1

                f0.write("{}\n".format(str(v0).rjust(3)))
                f1.write("{}\n".format(str(v1).rjust(3)))

    print(stats)

# tried output_file.close() here as well
print("done")
```